# Compiling from Visual Studio 2012 to g++?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012, gcc, g++

I have a c++ program compiled in Visual Studio 2012. It contains the boost library. Now, I want to compile this using the g++ compiler. What are the things I must be aware of? Things that will most likely silently break my code in random places.

For example I was always assuming `long` is 4 bytes buy g++ treats this as 8 bytes. For this alone I need some changes.

And what version of gcc to use, 4.7.3, 4.6.4 or 4.8.2?

Comment: Many things you know may need revisiting. This is not a good place to enumerate false beliefs popular among MSVC users.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some of the things that you have to keep in mind. This list  is not comprehensive but are those things that are on top of my mind when I read your question.

1. pragma once : When using g++, you should gaurd file inclusion by using #ifndef, #define and #endif guards.
2. Header inclusion : VS 2012 is very lenient and does not make a fuss of forward or backward slash while including headers. g++ will be strict in enforcing them.
3. If you are using Win32 threads / mutex, it is best to shift to std::thread. If you are using boost for threads, you are OK.

The version of gcc you can use and get away with depends on your usage of C++11 features. gcc was always ahead of Microsoft in implementing C++11 features and you should be OK with an older version of gcc too. I cannot answer this question unless I understand what c++11 features you are using in your code. It is safe to say that the more recent version of gcc will surely support what is available in Vs 2012.

Comment: Gcc (Gcc´s precomiler) can proceess #pragma once too. The thing abouert / or \ is a OS thing. And if (s)he is still on Windows: If (s)he needs OS-specific things from the Thread stuff, why not use it?

Comment: I use the boost asio library. Aside from this, I don't think I use c++11 features.

Comment: @deviantfan: No, the `/` versus `\ ` thing in headers is not really an OS thing. The preprocessor deals with them, if only because it needs to deal with `-I` command-line arguments. It's really GCC's decision to pass `\ ` on to the OS. IIRC, Visual C++ substitutes `\ ` for `/` before passing it to Windows.

Answer (score 3):

if you wrote valid and good  C++ code without using specific libraries you should be aware of nothing.